# Multiple JQuery toggles on one form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, toggle

I have a form for which some of the fields have expanding boxes attached. It looks a little like this (a few times over with slight variations):

```
<a class="label toggle" rel="toggle[time_allowed]">
  <label for="file_time_allowed" id="time_allowed_label">
    Time Allowed (mins)
  </label>
</a>
<%= form.text_field :time_allowed, :id => "time_allowed" %>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="expand_me" id="time_allowed_toggle" style="display:none;"><br />
  <div class="linkExpand expandDiv">
Set a time limit.<br /><br />
  </div>    
</div>
```

I have this JQuery to expand the `.expand_me` div when the user clicks on any `.toggle`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".expand_me").first().toggle("blind",{},500);
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

#### Two questions:

1. If I double- or triple-click on `.toggle`, 2-3 `.expand_me` divs toggle underneath it. Apparently, my current function is not always calling the next `.expand_me` but rather the next one that isn't currently animating. How can I make sure the toggle function always and only targets the next div regardless of its animation state?
2. I wanted to break the queueing of animations that JQuery natively builds up by adding `.stop()` to my toggle line, as in:

   ```
   $(this).nextAll(".expand_me").first().stop().toggle("blind",{},500);
   ```

   Since I have the issue with #1 I wasn't able to test if this works. If it doesn't, how can I ensure that a newbie who double-clicks on a div isn't met with a confusing double animation?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if you use just `.next()` rather than `.nextAll().first()`:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xdH82/3/

Or if you use the standard `.toggle()` rather than the extended one from jQuery-UI:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xdH82/4/

I don't know why there's a difference but a tour of the jQuery internals would probably be revealing. If you play around with single and double clicking in here:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Nudkh/

Then you'll see that the `.nextAll()` list excludes the currently animating element but I don't know why.

In any case, `.next('.expand_me')` exactly matches your intent so I'd just go with that and move on. OTOH, this difference between `.next()` and `.nextAll().first()` is probably going to be bugging me for days, hopefully someone will offer an explanation to ease my mind.

**UPDATE:** If you watch the animation with a DOM inspector (such as WebKit's "inspect element") you'll see that jQuery-UI's extended `.toggle` is wrapping the animated element in an extra `<div>` during the animation. So, if you say `.nextAll('.expand_me')` it won't find the `.expand_me` that you want as it won't be a sibling anymore: it will be the child of a temporary sibling. The `.next('.clear').next('.expand_me')` will conveniently fail to find anything as the temporary wrapper will block the direct path "this -> .clear -> .expand_me" and the click handler won't do anything on the second click of the double click.

I probably should have gone straight into the jQuery-UI source to figure out the odd `.nextAll()` behavior. Oh well, at least I know what's going on now.

**UPDATE 2:** A better approach than all this `.next` business would be to explicitly tie the link to the toggling panel:

```
<a data-panel="panel-1">
    <!--...-->
</a>
<!--...-->
<div id="panel-1" class="expand_me">
    <!--...-->
</div>
```

And:

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('panel')).stop().toggle('blind', { }, 500);
});
```

If you have an older jQuery then you might have to use `.attr('data-panel')` instead of `.data('panel')`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pmQR7/1/

Comment: @mu - it doesn't work if I use either `.next(".expand_me")` (nothing at all) or `.next()` (toggles the wrong elements). Am I using the command incorrectly?

Comment: @mu - I think the reason `.next()` isn't working is because there are elements in between the `a` tag and the `.expand_me`. It's all I can think of so far...

Comment: @sscirrus: Right, I tossed the `<div class="clear">` stuff from my jsfiddles to simplify things. Try `$(this).next('.clear').next(".expand_me").toggle` instead.

Comment: @sscirrus: Check my update at the end of my answer. I figured out why your `.nextAll` was causing problems when used with jQuery-UI's extended `.toggle`.

Comment: @sscirrus: If `.next('.clear').next('.expand_me')` doesn't work then try `.next('.clear').next('input').next('.expand_me')`.

Comment: @mu - Thanks a lot for all the effort. I'm going to look into this tomorrow and see what headway I can make. Talk to you soon.

Comment: @sscirrus: UPDATE2 is probably your best bet, less fragile and more explicit than `.next().next().next()...`. The `.nextAll` behavior was an interesting problem.